# Implicit Bearer flow for swagger asp..net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

Is there a way to automatically put bearer token to every request in Swagger?
I don't want to use oauth implicit flow where I should interact with identity.

I'd like to provide swagger an endpoint to my api where it could take access token and automatically put it to every request.

Answer (score 1):

In your startup.s class:

```
// prevent from mapping "sub" claim to nameidentifier.
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("sub");

var identityUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrl");

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = identityUrl;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.Audience = "demo_api";
});
```

SwaggerGen

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
      ...
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
       {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
            {
                Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                {
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrl")}/connect/authorize"),
                    TokenUrl = new Uri($"{configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrl")}/connect/token"),
                    Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "api1", "Demo API - full access" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Operation filter

```
options.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
```

The implementation

```
public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var hasAuthorize = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any() ||
                           context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>().Any();

        if (!hasAuthorize) return;

        var unauthorizedHashCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.GetHashCode().ToString();
        var unauthorizedDescription = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString();

        var forbiddenHashCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden.GetHashCode().ToString();
        var forbiddenDescription = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden.ToString();

        operation.Responses.TryAdd(unauthorizedHashCode, new OpenApiResponse { Description = unauthorizedDescription });
        operation.Responses.TryAdd(forbiddenHashCode, new OpenApiResponse { Description = forbiddenDescription });

        var oAuthScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
        };

        operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                [ oAuthScheme ] = new [] { "api1" }
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Use this

```
// Keep both UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization IN THIS ORDER
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Use Swagger

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
        {
            s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Your awesome project name");

            s.OAuthAppName("My API - Swagger");
            s.OAuthClientId("client");

            // Should match the client RedirectUrl in the IdentityServer
            s.OAuth2RedirectUrl("https://localhost:5001/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html");
        });
```

Your controller

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")] // TODO: Take care of the versioning
public class IndentityController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
```

Now in the IdentityServer Project. The ApiResources:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        };
    }
```

And finally, your Client should look like this:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html" },
    AllowedScopes = { "api1" },
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    RequireConsent = false
}
```

And for a complete source code, take a look at the [eShopOnContainers repo](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dotnet3-migration/dev-dotnet3)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

the next code worked for me

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v2",
                Title = "PRJ API",
                Description = "PRJ Web API",
            });

            if (oktaIssuer != null)
            {
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Okta", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{oktaIssuer}/v1/authorize"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                { "profile", "Access profile" },
                                { "email", "Email"},
                                { "openid", "OpenID"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Okta" },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header
                        },
                       
                        new string[] {}
                    }
                });
                c.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
            }
```

Also those strings must be the same!
[image: AddSecurityDefinition&AddSecurityRequirement]